# Custom AppCompatButton getting wrong colors on Android 5 (Api 21)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

So I've implemented a custom button for our app, the implementation works perfect on Android 6 and up but I run into an issue on Android 5, where the background color doesn't get applied until I press the button once. Then it looks as it should.

- [Buttons not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQFU.png)
- [Buttons correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxyBE.png)

The implementation looks like this:

```
class MpButton @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = R.style.ButtonStyle) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

private val toScale = 0.9f
private val fromScale = 1f

init {
    var style = 0
    var allCaps = false

    attrs?.let {
        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(it, R.styleable.MpButton)
        style = a.getInt(R.styleable.MpButton_MpButtonColor, 0)
        allCaps = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MpButton_MpButtonAllcaps, false)
        a.recycle()
    }

    when (style) {
        WHITE -> {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mp_button_white)
            this.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
        }
        RED -> {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mp_button_red)
            this.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
        }
        BLACK -> {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mp_button_black)
            this.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.mp_black))
        }
        BLUE -> {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mp_button_blue)
            this.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
        }
        YELLOW -> {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mp_button_yellow)
            this.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
        }
        else -> {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mp_button_green)
            this.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
        }
    }

    this.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    val padding = Utils.convertDpToPixel(context, 5)
    this.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding)
    this.isAllCaps = allCaps
}

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when(event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            this.animate().scaleX(toScale).scaleY(toScale).setDuration(100).start()
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            this.animate().scaleX(fromScale).scaleY(fromScale).setDuration(100).start()
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}

companion object {
    const val WHITE = 1
    const val RED = 2
    const val BLACK = 3
    const val BLUE = 4
    const val YELLOW = 5
}
}
```

For info Ill also add the XML for one of the colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/mp_black">
<item>
    <selector
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/jungle_green" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/forest" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_enabled="false">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/mp_gray_5" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
</item>
</ripple>
```

As a last ill copy the part of the XML of the view aswell to give as much info as possible:

```
<se.motesplatsen.app.ui.controls.MpButton
    android:id="@+id/btnStartLogin"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:text="@string/DEFAULT_LOGIN"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:MpButtonAllcaps="true"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnStartBecomeMember"/>

<se.motesplatsen.app.ui.controls.MpButton
    android:id="@+id/btnStartBecomeMember"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/BECOME_MEMBER_BUTTON"
    app:MpButtonColor="1"
    app:MpButtonAllcaps="true"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvStartDesc"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnStartLogin"/>
```

**UPDATE & SOLUTION!:** 
Finally got this to work! Solution was to remove

`android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"`

Im guessing it somehow interferes with the ripple animation on certain Android versions. So for anyone else that have my issue, check so you dont have Ripple togheter with fadeduration in the selector :)!

Comment: So after getting back to this issue as im nearing release, I found the issue for anyone else interested:

Using Ripple with selector with exitFadeDuration makes the background resource not appear before you click it. I have no idea why but removing it makes it now work in all colors :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <size android:height="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item  android:bottom="2dip" android:top="2dip" android:left="2dip" android:right="2dip">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/Transparent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

this is exactly look like your correct button

Comment: See comment above, Im pretty sure its not an XML issue, but something with Android 5

Comment: Finally got this to work! Solution was to remove 

`android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="5dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="@color/Transparent"
    />
```

just use this as background you are using on pressed state in your file

Comment: Thanks for your responses, however im not sure what you mean, my issue is not that its not correct in the XML its that Android 5 doesnt render it correctly until I press it the first time. If you look at the correct picture there are 2 buttons and both of thoose are correct, and they look like that in all android versions above 5. The left ones are from Android 5 where the xml doesnt seem to apply until I press the button one time...